# Python - pywin32 getting bitmap of client area?

Tags: python, winapi, python-2.7, bitmap, pywin32

I'm trying to use the pywin32 module to get the bitmap of a window's client area. Using the exact code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18733486/python-win32api-bitmap-getbitmapbits) I am able to get the bitmap of the entire desktop. Specifically, when I look at the bits returned, there are 4*(desktop-pixels) number of entries. However, when I try to do something similar for a window or client area, I get less entries returned then there are pixels. My code for getting the window bitmap is below. However, I have tried several variations on it. For example, replacing the window parts with the client area, setting the (nXSrc, nYSrc) to zero, etc. Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong? Thank you much!

**Code:**

```
windowName = "MyProcessWindow"
windowHandle = win32ui.FindWindow(None, windowName).GetSafeHwnd()
windowRectangle = win32gui.GetWindowRect(windowHandle)
width = windowRectangle[2]-windowRectangle[0]
height = windowRectangle[3]-windowRectangle[1]
win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(windowHandle)
windowDeviceContext = win32gui.GetWindowDC(windowHandle)
deviceContextObject = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(windowDeviceContext)
compatibleDeviceContext = deviceContextObject.CreateCompatibleDC()
dataBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
dataBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(compatibleDeviceContext, width, height)
compatibleDeviceContext.SelectObject(dataBitMap)
compatibleDeviceContext.BitBlt((0,0), (width, height), deviceContextObject, (windowRectangle[0],windowRectangle[1]), win32con.SRCCOPY)
info = dataBitMap.GetInfo()
bits = dataBitMap.GetBitmapBits(False)
print info
print len(bits)
print (width*height)
```

**Print results:**

```
{'bmType': 0, 'bmWidthBytes': 92, 'bmHeight': 526, 'bmBitsPixel': 1, 'bmPlanes': 1, 'bmWidth': 728}
48392
382928
```

Comment: From a quick glance, it looks like you're off by a factor of 8… you're not just mixing up bit counts and byte counts, are you? Also, I note that `bmBitsPerPixel` and `bmPlanes` are both 1, which means this is a black&white image. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Meanwhile, isn't `GetBitmapBits` deprecated since NT 3.51 or so?

Comment: @abarnert: It's not a factor of 8 exactly. It's somewhat close but not quite. I noticed the bmBitsPerPixel too, and after some more research I tried to fix that by initializing the dataBitMap with more bmBitsPerPixel, but it immediately goes back to one on the CreateCompatibleBitmap. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: @abarnert: I guess part of the problem is that I don't know enough about the structure of the bitmap bits that are returned. For the desktop bitmap it was just a set of four numbers for RGBX returned for each pixel. But this appears not to be the case in the clientDC.

Comment: The `info` tells you how to interpret the bits. In this case, each number is 8 B&W pixels. Which may not be easy to directly read in pywin32. But at any rate, you don't want to figure out how to deal with the B&W pixels, you want to get the RGBX pixels instead. And I think my answer may be what you need.

Comment: The docs on this are really confusing. There used to be different explanations of everything in the MFC docs, so if the Win32 stuff made no sense you could try there, but that no longer seems to be available…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is this:

```
dataBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(compatibleDeviceContext, width, height)
```

You want to create a bitmap that's compatible with the *source* DC, which has the appropriate color depth and other features. Then you can select that into the target DC, which will give *it* the appropriate color depth, size, and other features.

Instead, you're creating one that's compatible with the *target* DC, which at this point is a 1x1 black&white DC, as explained in the [`CreateCompatibleDC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) docs. Then you select that into the target DC, leaving it exactly as it started.

That's why you end up with a bitmap with 1 plane of 1bpp.

See the [Capturing a Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) sample (in C, and horrible C at that, but hopefully you can follow it) for an example of how to do it. But I believe this is the only step you're doing wrong.

Comment: That was certainly it. Thank you much. Struggled for way longer on that than I should have.