# wxPython - Get existing windowDC/handle using wx python module?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

I've been looking into using the wx python package on Windows 7. Specifically, I would like to be able to get the image data of a existing window (i.e. not a window opened by the python program). It appears I can do this by getting the window's device context, creating a compatible device context, copying the bitmap, and then using it how I like from there. The problem is that I can't seem to find the way to get the device context (or the handle) of an existing window. I only see ways to get them from windows the python program using wx created. How might I be able to go about doing this? Thank you much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wx may not have a way to do this.

The Windows APIs you need are pretty simple, and you can use them through `win32api` (or `ctypes` if you prefer, but that's a lot more work).

First, I don't know how you're planning to identify the window you want. If you have its class and name, you can just [`FindWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (or, if it may not be a top-level window, [`FindWindowEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). If you want to search by something else, you will probably need to call [`EnumWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (plus [`EnumChildWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) recursively, if you're not sure it's a top-level window).

At this point, you can just call `wx.Windows.AssociateHandle` to attach a `wx.Window` object to the HWND.

If you can't do that for whatever reason, [`GetDC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144871%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) gives you a display context for an HWND. You can then create a memory DC, or get the DC for the native window under underlying your wx window, and [`BitBlt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from one to the other.

Comment: `AssociateHandle` can indeed be used to work with windows created outside of the Python application.

Comment: @FogleBird: Thanks! Let me edit the answer, because that makes things simpler.

Comment: Ok. I was thinking this might be the case. I was trying to do what you're suggesting, but was running into problems as I [am looking for in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19980277/python-pywin32-getting-bitmap-of-client-area). However, I wasn't getting the solution there and I've been having trouble hunting that down on my own. That was when I found wx and thought it might be a solution.

Comment: Oh! Maybe the update of using AssociateHandle will work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on the other answer, try this code (untested, I'm not on Windows right now)...

```
# first use FindWindow or FindWindowEx to determine window handle
frame = wx.Frame(None)
frame.AssociateHandle(handle)
dc = wx.ClientDC(frame)
width, height = dc.GetSize()
bitmap = wx.EmptyBitmap(width, height)
mdc = wx.MemoryDC(bitmap)
mdc.Blit(0, 0, width, height, dc, 0, 0)
del mdc
bitmap.SaveFile('output.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
```

Comment: Also, check out my code here which draws snowflakes on the desktop - you can also see how to use ctypes to use the FindWindow function. https://github.com/fogleman/wxSnow/blob/master/wxsnow.py